# How to make Generic Repository able to automatically infer the type of primary key?

Tags: c#

The following code already works but I think specifying `int` in the following

```
var repo = new Repository<Student, int>(students);
```

is a bit redundant. I want to simplify as follows:

```
var repo = new Repository<Student>(students);
```

How should I modify the `IRepository` and `Repository` below to achieve what I want?

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
class Entity<TKey>
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; } = default!;
}


interface IRepository<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity : Entity<TKey>
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
}

class Repository<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity : Entity<TKey>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<TEntity> data;
    public Repository(IEnumerable<TEntity> data) => this.data = data;
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll() => data;
}


class Student : Entity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var students = new Student[]
        {
           new Student { Name="Andy"},
           new Student { Name="Bob"},
           new Student { Name="Cindy"}
        };

        var repo = new Repository<Student, int>(students);
    }
}
```

Note: My entities can have primary keys of type `string`, `int`, `Guid`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c# cannot do partial type inference. In some cases you can do a workaround by creating a object with one generic type parameter, and using a method on this that lets you infer the other. But I do not see any way to do that in this specific case.

But you could perhaps use a static method to let you infer both types, :

```
public static class Repository{
    public static Repository<TEntity, TKey> Create<TEntity, TKey>(IEnumerable<TEntity> data) 
        where TEntity : Entity<TKey> 
    => new Repository<TEntity, TKey>(data);
}
...
var repo = Repository.Create(students);
```

The thing here is that constructors cannot do type inference, but static methods can.

Comment: How about `builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Student, int>, Repository<Student, int>>();`? Can it also be simplified with a static method?
`

Comment: @TheRealMasochist not the same way, since there is no object to do inference on. But you could do an extension like `static void AddRepo<T, TKey>(this IServiceCollection self) where ... => self.AddScoped<IRepository<T, TKey>, Repository<T, TKey>>() `

Comment: I found the simplest one: `builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<,>), typeof(GenericRepository<,>));`